# There is a sort of window closing upon launching my app, only in Android versions higher than 6. Is it about the Permissions?

Tags: android, permissions

I have an Activity with a library that asks for its own permissions that happen to collide with my required permissions, so I just override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` and let that library ask the permissions instead. The override is as follows:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        Log.i("perms", permissions.length+" "+requestCode);
        int indexOfReadStorage = 0;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < permissions.length; i++)
        {
            Log.i("perms_len", permissions[i]+" "+requestCode);
            if(permissions[i].contains("READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"))
            {
                indexOfReadStorage = i;
            }
        }
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[indexOfReadStorage] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission Granted
            Log.i("read_ext_storage_perm", "granted");
            populateFolderList();
        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            //Toast.makeText(this, "READ_EXT_STORAGE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Where `requestCode == 4` (in my code my own requestCode for the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is set to 102).

However, now I have some kind of window closing animation right after I launch the app the second time and after that. This doesn't happen when I tested the app in Lollipop, so it must be something in Marshmallow that makes this happen, and I'm suspecting it's the permissions check in the library.

Is it true? If it is, how do I resolve this? If it isn't, what might be the real cause?

Comment: Are you sure you check whether you already have the permission before you make the permission request?

Comment: I can't, the aforementioned library does the checking and makes the request.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the library requesting permission at the beginning of the activity with `VmaxSDK.init(this)` in `onCreate()` [said library was VMAX].

So I just moved it to the next Activity, and it all goes fine.